# How to save a position in a vector for later insertion?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to remove data from a vector, use it, and later reinsert it into the vector at the same position.

I am going to use this as a cache for "things to send", reinserting in case of "failure to send", while new items have a higher-priority. Only one thread will remove things from this cache, so no worries on it being smaller than initially, other threads will only be able to grow it.

I have tried this simple test code, but I found a weird result, I would to understand why it happened and how to fix it:

```
void printVector(std::vector<int> &vector) {
    for (auto i : vector) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> states_cache {1, 2, 3};

    printVector(states_cache); // prints: 1 2 3
    auto pos = states_cache.end();
    int i = states_cache.back();
    states_cache.pop_back();

    std::cout << "i1: " << i << std::endl;
    printVector(states_cache); // prints: 1 2 

    states_cache.push_back(4);
    states_cache.push_back(5);
    states_cache.push_back(6);
    printVector(states_cache);  // prints: 1 2 4 5 6 


    states_cache.insert(pos - 1, i); // Here I can see at the debugger that pos inner memory structure value changes from 129 to 4, whatever this means

    printVector(states_cache); // prints: 33 1 2 4 5 6
}
```

the last `printVector` prints:

> 33 1 2 4 5 6

I can see the first item being evaluated at `printVector` is the number `33`, so not the number `3` being printed twice.

I was expecting it to be:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

As if the `3` was removed, "used" and later reinserted at the same position as it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto pos = states_cache.end();` At this point, `pos` is not a position, but an [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to the vector.

Every time you push elements to the vector, end of vector iterator - which your `pos` currently holds - is invalidated, so after those pushes the `pos` iterator is no longer valid and not usable.

If you want to insert element at the position the element originally held, you would have to remember the index of the element being removed, and than convert that index to the iterator for `insert` call.

To get the index, you can use `std::distance` with two iterators - one of the element, second to the beginning of the vector. For example, to get the index of the last element in the vector, you can use

```
auto ix = std::distance(vec.begin(), vec.end()) - 1;
```

Also please note this assumes the vector is not empty.

Comment: And how can I get the index of the position? In my case I could use `size`, but is it there a solution to get the index of any item?

Comment: @mFeinstein added to the answer.

Comment: `std::distance` isn't very happy, I am getting an error "No matching function for call to 'distance'", maybe it's missing some `<>` template types?

Comment: `vec.begin()` and `vec.back()` are not the same type, I guess that's what the compiler is complaining, have you managed to compile that code?

Comment: @mFeinstein but of course! Sorry, it was a typo. `vec.end()` was supposed to be there.

Comment: Thanks Sergey! I am using `vec.size() - 1` as I think it's simpler, but I learned a lot, your answer covers all the cases

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that vector iterators may be invalidated in case of a reallocation: they are basically pointers to the memory the vector data resides in. When you do a `push_back` the vector may be forced to reallocate to another address in memory, thus any iterator that you have cannot be used any more.

You need to save as position the numeric index, not the iterator.

To insert back the element you then can do

```
states_cache.insert(states_cache.begin() + index, element);
```

Comment: I tried to use indexes to `insert` but `insert` only works with iterator, how can I save the index value AND use it later with `insert`?

Comment: and how to I get `index`? From `size`?

Comment: @mFeinstein: to use the equivalent to `end()` you need to use `index=states_cache.size()-1;`